# Copy all debug build settings in Xcode

Tags: xcode, configuration

I want to move all the build settings stuff to Xcode config files (http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360), however in Xcode 4, when I **select all and copy**, it said "cannot copy build settings with multiple values", the reason is Debug and Release settings are mixed.

So how can I copy only Debug information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left of each multiple setting you'll see a disclosure triangle when you mouse over it. Click it to see individual settings. Then, copy one by one.

Answer (score 1):

What I just did to copy setting, for example `Build Settings > Linker > Other Linker Flags`, is I made my edits in one target first. Then I toggle the "Show Version Editor" control in Xcode and can see where I made the change and just make edits in that mode. I suppose you need to be hooked up to a version control system for this to work.